# Selenium / xpath - Can't find element, finding parent div

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

> Using Python 3+ and Selenium > IE Driver

I am running a python script to automate filling out a form on a page. The reason for finding the parent element is because there are multiple elements with the same class and no other identifiers other then the text based title.

***HTML:***

```
<div class="pg_BoxContents"> /* Div I am trying to select */
<div class="Title">Replay Permissions:</div>
</div>
```

***Python / Selenium:***

```
replay_form = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//span[contains(text(),'Replay Permissions:')]/ancestor::div[contains(@class, 'pg_BoxContents')]")
```

***Error:***

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to find element with xpath == //span[contains(text(),'Details:')]/ancestor::div[contains(@class, 'pg_BoxContents')]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace:

```
//span[contains(text(),'Replay Permissions:')]/ancestor::div[contains(@class, 'pg_BoxContents')]
```

with:

```
//div[contains(text(),'Replay Permissions:')]/ancestor::div[contains(@class, 'pg_BoxContents')]
```

You are using `//span[...` where there is no `span` in HTML you have provided. But there is a `div`.